# transform: translateY not working in iOS

Tags: ios, css, centering

i have div with this code and it's vertically centering content perfectly in all browsers except safari. On iphones and ipads I can't vertically center it. It seems it's 100% from top, so just under the div.:

```
.quotecont {    
max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 125px);
max-width: -o-calc(100% - 125px);
max-width: -ms-calc(100% - 125px);
max-width: calc(100% - 125px);
white-space: normal;
width: 850px;
text-align: left;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform:translateY(-50%); /* IE */
-moz-transform:translateY(-50%); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:translateY(-50%); /* Opera */
white-space: normal;
}
```

In this div I have content with different heights, so I can' put it directly to one place from top.

If you want to watch it (or the code), it's on this web in yellow box almost at the bottom of the homepage: http://kadernictvi-gepard.cz/

Thank you for your help and have a nice day,
Michal

Comment: You may have to prefix the "translate" declaration as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do it. Can you give me just a push how to do it?

Comment: Just put `-webkit-` in front of `translate` in your `webkit-transform` statement...it might work.

Comment: You mean like -webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(-50%); or transform:-webkit-translateY(-50%);?

Comment: These 2 codes doesn't work.

Comment: Oh.. I seem to recall that Safari doesn't support individual translate properties like X & Y.  Only translate by itself. You'd have to check.